# NullPointer exception when accessing other viewbean as Managed Property

Tags: jsf

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "homeBean")
    @SessionScoped
    public class HomeBean {

        public String msg="";

        @ManagedProperty(value="#{searchBean}")
        private StartBean startBean;

        public void fetch(){
            setMsg(getStartBean().getServer().getChat());
        }
    }
```

I get error when calling `fetch` method. `startBean` is returned null although the bean is created when user login at the start.

Comment: What if you use CDI instead JSF beans? Replace `@ManagedBean` for `@Named` and `@SessionScoped` (javax.enterprise.context). Then just inject the bean: `@Inject private StartBean startBean`.

Comment: Check if you have the setStartBean(...) setter for startBean